# Loop text data based on column value in data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have a dataset called data_set_tweets.csv as below

> created_at,tweet,retweet_count
> 7/29/2021 2:40,Great Sunny day for Cricket at London,3
> 7/29/2021 10:40,Great Score put on by England batting,0
> 7/29/2021 11:50,England won the match,1

And what I was trying to do is to get the below output in to a data frame.
Which means I want to iterate the text in the **tweet** column based on the **retweet_count** value with same created_at values on that particular tweet

***Below is the expected output for my dataset***

> created_at,tweet
> 7/29/2021 2:40,Great Sunny day for Cricket at London
> 7/29/2021 2:40,Great Sunny day for Cricket at London
> 7/29/2021 2:40,Great Sunny day for Cricket at London
> 7/29/2021 2:40,Great Sunny day for Cricket at London
> 7/29/2021 10:40,Great Score put on by England batting
> 7/29/2021 11:50,England won the match
> 7/29/2021 11:50,England won the match

Below is how I started my approach

```
import pandas as pd

def iterateTweets():
tweets = pd.read_csv(r'data_set_tweets.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(tweets, columns=['created_at', 'tweet', 'retweet_count'])
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
df['retweet_count'] = df['retweet_count'].apply(lambda x: str(x))

# print(df)
return df

if __name__ == '__main__':

print(iterateTweets())
```

I'm beginner to data frame and python can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for duplicated columns, [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is for using and dropping column:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'data_set_tweets.csv')

df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.pop('retweet_count') + 1)].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
           created_at                                  tweet
0 2021-07-29 02:40:00  Great Sunny day for Cricket at London
1 2021-07-29 02:40:00  Great Sunny day for Cricket at London
2 2021-07-29 02:40:00  Great Sunny day for Cricket at London
3 2021-07-29 02:40:00  Great Sunny day for Cricket at London
4 2021-07-29 10:40:00  Great Score put on by England batting
5 2021-07-29 11:50:00                  England won the match
6 2021-07-29 11:50:00                  England won the match
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.repeat(df['retweet_count'] + 1)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

If you want to remove the `retweet_count` column:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.repeat(df['retweet_count'] + 1)).reset_index(drop=True).drop('retweet_count', axis=1)
```

Or:

```
col = df.pop('retweet_count') + 1
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.repeat(col)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

`df` output:

```
           created_at                                  tweet
0 2021-07-29 02:40:00  Great Sunny day for Cricket at London
1 2021-07-29 02:40:00  Great Sunny day for Cricket at London
2 2021-07-29 02:40:00  Great Sunny day for Cricket at London
3 2021-07-29 02:40:00  Great Sunny day for Cricket at London
4 2021-07-29 10:40:00  Great Score put on by England batting
5 2021-07-29 11:50:00                  England won the match
6 2021-07-29 11:50:00                  England won the match
```

Or use `loc` with `enumerate`:

```
df.loc[sum([[i] * (v + 1) for i, v in enumerate(df['retweet_count'])], [])].reset_index(drop=True)
```